# How do.you make an embedded youtube video.autoplay?

Tags: html, css

I am trying (and failing) to make an embedded youtube video autoplay

Here is the code:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" 
        src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/jH1RNk8954Q" 
        frameborder="0" 
        allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" 
        allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

is there a way to make this autoplay? If so please could I have it.

In HTML and CSS by the way

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en

Sample there for autoplay:

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"
  frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Should probably note that autoplay videos won't have sound in most browsers. Users are expected to **choose** to play a video if it's anything other than a background.

Comment: When I use that it says video unavailable